# Can a space in a network name cause this issue?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater, wireless-extender

I am trying to setup an extender for a network. I am using a Wavlink AC 1200 dual band outdoor extender in repeater mode. I have entered all the network information correctly. What I am seeing is odd. When I look at the main setup page, it shows that the extender is up and running. I can connect to it with other devices. The problem is that there is no internet access. The thing is that the network name is cut-off. For example - the network name is "BusinessName A", but in the setup for Wavlink it shows only "BusinessName" and no internet. This network was setup before I came on to setup the extender and other devices are attached. I was hoping to not change the name. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I never use spaces in a Network Name (SSID).  That makes for best transferability and fewer errors. I suggest changing to a shorter name (12 characters or less) and no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:  [SSID requirements](https://www.routersecurity.org/SSID.php#:%7E:text=See%20Firmware%20201412%3A%20Wi%2DFi,have%20spaces%20or%20special%20characters.)

> In April 2016, something called a bttn had problems with SSIDs
> containing spaces or special characters. See Firmware 201412: Wi-Fi
> SSID and password cannot have spaces or special characters.

Remove your spaces and your network names will work correctly.

Comment: Many devices are fussy about SSID's. My Fitbit Aria scales wouldn't connect when I had a `.` in my SSID name.

Comment: @John - The way the author explains it is that the SSID being listed in the configuration page does NOT have a space, but when their device lists the SSIDs that are visible, there is a space but the author isn't being very verbose with information.

Comment: One name in the question did have a space. …  (space)A